# Robots.txt disallowing particular type of URL

Tags: robots.txt

I want to exclude this URL from bots:-
test.com/p/12345/qwerty

But allow this URL:-
test.com/p/12345

Will this line work?

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: */p/*/*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [tutorial](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/) there is no need for the * at the beginning. It should be:

```
User-Agent: * 
Disallow: /p/*/*
```

Note that this will have the side effect of blocking bots on an address like test.com/p/abc/def

 
In order to do the exact functionality you are asking for and nothing more (i.e. no side effects), use this:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /p/12345/qwerty
```

test.com/p/12345 will be allowed by default.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.